# Merge records based on key, with priority

Tags: sql, sqlite

In an SQLite database, I have monuments identified by a key. For each key, I have name+description in various languages (a row per language) about that monument. Some of the names and descriptions are missing:

```
key | language | name         | description
======================================================
3   | English  | *NULL*       | A museum in Paris
3   | French   | Le Louvre    | Un musée à Paris
7   | English  | Manneken     | *NULL*
7   | French   | Manneken Pis | Une statue à Bruxelles
9   | Spanish  | Casa Batllo  | *NULL*
```

**My goal**: I want to merge the rows that have the same key, while giving priority to English. Expected result:

```
key | name         | description
===========================================
3   | Le Louvre    | A museum in Paris
7   | Manneken     | Une statue à Bruxelles
9   | Casa Batllo  | *NULL*
```

Explanation:

- Monument 3: Description from English, name from another language because English has no name.
- Monument 7:  from English, description from another language because English has no description.
- Monument 9: All from Spanish because English has no information about it at all.

**How to implement this query with SQLite SQL?**
If possible, I am hoping for a query that does not become huge with 20 properties in addition to name+description.

---

Here is my current attempt, it merges rows by key, but unfortunately I don't know how to tell it to prefer English if several languages are available for a field:

```
SELECT
    key,
    MAX(name) AS name,
    MAX(description) AS description
FROM
    monuments
GROUP BY
    key;
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible to use subqueries to look up each value:

```
SELECT key,
       (SELECT name
        FROM monuments
        WHERE key = k.key
        ORDER BY language != 'English'
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS name,
       (SELECT description
        FROM monuments
        WHERE key = k.key
        ORDER BY language != 'English'
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS description
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT key
      FROM monuments) AS k;
```

Alternatively, the MAX() idea is not bad, but you have to to modify the values to ensure that they are ordered correctly, and restore them afterwards:

```
SELECT key,
       substr(max(name),        2) AS name,
       substr(max(description), 2) AS description
FROM (SELECT key,
             (language = 'English') || name        AS name,
             (language = 'English') || description AS description
      FROM monuments)
GROUP BY key;
```

Answer (score -1):

The idea is to left join yor result and result for english rows only with priority to English
Unfortunately, sqlite3 has bug for aggregate functions, executes all aggregate functions on outer level and i cant use MIN or MAX, i use just field instead, absolutely no warranty this bug will not dissapear in future versions

```
select a.key,coalesce(b.name,a.name) name, coalesce(b.description,a.description) description from 
(SELECT
    key,
    name,
    description
FROM
    muzeums 
 group by key   ) a
left join 
(SELECT
    key,
    name,
    description
FROM
    muzeums where language='English') b
on a.key=b.key
```